# How to modify the value of a JsonNode recursively using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonpath, jackson-databind

Requirements:
I want to apply some functions on the inner values of the `JsonNode`. The functions can be different eg:- `lowercasing` some values or appending something to the values or replace the values with something. How can I achieve that using `Jackson` library? Note that the structure of the JSON data can be different which means I want to build a generic system which will accept some path expression which will basically decide where to change. I want to use functional programming style, so that I can pass these functions as arguments.

eg:

input:

```
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "values": [
    {
      "id": "xyz1",
      "sal": "1234",
      "addresses": [
        {
          "id": "add1",
          "name": "ABCD",
          "dist": "123"
        },
        {
          "id": "add2",
          "name": "abcd3",
          "dist": "345"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "xyz2",
      "sal": "3456",
      "addresses": [
        {
          "id": "add1",
          "name": "abcd",
          "dist": "123"
        },
        {
          "id": "add2",
          "name": "XXXXX",
          "dist": "345"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In this case I have to two functions basically, `lowercase()` and `convert_to_number()`. I want to apply `lowercase()` function on all the `"name"` attribute inside all the `"addresses"` of each `"value"`.
same goes for `convert_to_number()` , but for all the `"dist"` attribute.

So, basically the `JSON` expressions will be something like below for the functions:

```
lowercase() : /values/*/addresses/*/name
convert_to_number() : /values/*/addresses/*/dist
```

output:

```
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "values": [
    {
      "id": "xyz1",
      "sal": "1234",
      "addresses": [
        {
          "id": "add1",
          "name": "abcd",
          "dist": 123
        },
        {
          "id": "add2",
          "name": "abcd3",
          "dist": 345
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "xyz2",
      "sal": "3456",
      "addresses": [
        {
          "id": "add1",
          "name": "abcd",
          "dist": 123
        },
        {
          "id": "add2",
          "name": "xxxx",
          "dist": 345
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Client code:

```
JsonNode jsonNode = ...
applyFunctionsRecursivelyBasedOnExpr(JsonNode jsonNode, String expr, Function )
```

Comment: output dist is still string...

Comment: updated the code.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? Were below answers helpful?

Answer (score 7):

As @MichalZiober in his answer already pointed out,
[JsonPath](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path) offers a much more powerful API than Jackson,
when you need to do JSON-path-based operations.

Using methods [`JsonPath.parse`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/2.4.0/com/jayway/jsonpath/JsonPath.html#parse-java.io.File-) and [`WriteContext.map`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/2.4.0/com/jayway/jsonpath/WriteContext.html#map-java.lang.String-com.jayway.jsonpath.MapFunction-com.jayway.jsonpath.Predicate...-)
you can solve your problem in just a few lines:

```
import java.io.File;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("input.json");
        String json = JsonPath.parse(file)
                .map("$.values[*].addresses[*].name", Main::lowerCase)
                .map("$.values[*].addresses[*].dist", Main::convertToNumber)
                .jsonString();
        System.out.println(json);
    }

    private static Object lowerCase(Object currentValue, Configuration configuration) {
        if (currentValue instanceof String)
            return ((String)currentValue).toLowerCase();
        return currentValue;
    }

    private static Object convertToNumber(Object currentValue, Configuration configuration) {
        if (currentValue instanceof String)
            return Integer.valueOf((String)currentValue);
        return currentValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Thomas! :) 
Very compact and straightforward solution!

Answer (score 4):

### JsonPath

You could use [`JsonPath`](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) library which has a better `JSON Path` handling. When `Jackson` supports only [JSON Pointer draft-ietf-appsawg-json-pointer-03](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-json-pointer-03). Take a look on [JsonPointer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonPointer.html) documentation. With `JsonPath` library you could do that in this way:

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import net.minidev.json.JSONArray;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        JsonModifier jsonModifier = new JsonModifier(jsonFile);
        Function<Map<String, Object>, Void> lowerCaseName = map -> {
            final String key = "name";
            map.put(key, map.get(key).toString().toLowerCase());
            return null;
        };
        Function<Map<String, Object>, Void> changeDistToNumber = map -> {
            final String key = "dist";
            map.put(key, Integer.parseInt(map.get(key).toString()));
            return null;
        };
        jsonModifier.update("$.values[*].addresses[*]", Arrays.asList(lowerCaseName, changeDistToNumber));
        jsonModifier.print();
    }
}

class JsonModifier {

    private final DocumentContext document;

    public JsonModifier(File json) throws IOException {
        this.document = JsonPath.parse(json);
    }

    public void update(String path, List<Function<Map<String, Object>, Void>> transformers) {
        JSONArray array = document.read(path);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            Object o = array.get(i);
            transformers.forEach(t -> {
                t.apply((Map<String, Object>) o);
            });
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(document.jsonString());
    }
}
```

Your path, should work on `JSON object`-s which are represented by `Map<String, Object>`. You can replace keys in given object, add them, remove them just like replacing, adding and removing keys in `Map`.

### Jackson

You can of course mock `JsonPath` feature by iterating over `Json Pointer`. For each `*` we need to create loop and iterate over it using counter and until node is not missing. Below you can see simple implementation:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonFile);

        Function<ObjectNode, Void> lowerCaseName = node -> {
            final String key = "name";
            node.put(key, node.get(key).asText().toLowerCase());
            return null;
        };
        Function<ObjectNode, Void> changeDistToNumber = node -> {
            final String key = "dist";
            node.put(key, Integer.parseInt(node.get(key).asText()));
            return null;
        };

        JsonModifier jsonModifier = new JsonModifier(root);
        jsonModifier.updateAddresses(Arrays.asList(lowerCaseName, changeDistToNumber));

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(root));
    }
}

class JsonModifier {

    private final JsonNode root;

    public JsonModifier(JsonNode root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public void updateAddresses(List<Function<ObjectNode, Void>> transformers) {
        String path = "/values/%d/addresses/%d";
        for (int v = 0; v < 100; v++) {
            int a = 0;
            do {
                JsonNode address = root.at(String.format(path, v, a++));
                if (address.isMissingNode()) {
                    break;
                }
                if (address.isObject()) {
                    transformers.forEach(t -> t.apply((ObjectNode) address));
                }
            } while (true);
            if (a == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This solution is slower than with `JsonPath` because we need to travers whole `JSON` tree `n` times where `n` number of matching nodes. Of course, our implementation could be a much faster using [`Streaming API`](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api).