# Simple JSON value parsing for Java 8

Tags: json, java-8, jackson, jettison

Java 8 here though I have Jackson and Jettison on my classpath already (as dependencies).

I am being given the following string of JSON (as an example):

```
{
    "widgets": {
        "email": "someone@example.com",
        "maxSize": 50
    },
    "environments": {
        "LOCAL": {
            "maxSize": "40"
        },
        "DEV": {
            "maxSize": "100"
        }
    },
    "fruits": [
        "apples",
        "oranges"
    ]
}
```

At runtime the values of the fields will be different.

I am just trying to read the value of `environments/DEV/maxSize` from this string; what is the simplest code I can write to extract this value?

Ideally there might be some built in Java 8 support for this type of thing, but if note, I hopefully either Jackson or Jettison ship with this capability without having to add a new jar/dependency to my project. Worst case scenario would be just using some kind of regex to strip out the value I suppose...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple option would be to use [`JsonPath`](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath). Nested properties can be pulled using a path specifier like `$.environments.DEV.maxSize`:

```
long maxSize = JsonPath.parse(json).read("$.environments.DEV.maxSize", Long.class);
```

With Jackson, this can be done either with `JsonNode`:

```
long maxSize = new ObjectMapper()
    .readTree(json)
    .get("environments").get("DEV").get("maxSize").asLong();
```

Or if you have a class that represents the data, you can deserialize to that:

```
MyConfig myConfig = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, MyConfig.class);
long maxSize = myConfig.getEnvironments().get(Environment.DEV).getMaxSize();
```

Comment: Thanks @jspcal (+1), but I'm hoping to find something built-in to Java 8, Jackson or Jettison as the ideal solution, then looking for something regex/string-bashing as a 2nd solution, and only considering adding a new jar dependency like JsonPath to my classpath as a hail mary fallback/last resort.

Comment: With Jackson, perhaps try `readTree` or `readValue` as above.

Comment: You can replace `Jackson` version with `JSON Pointer` example: `.readTree(json)
    .at("/environments/DEV/maxSize").asLong()`. See: [How to modify the value of a JsonNode recursively using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55560223/how-to-modify-the-value-of-a-jsonnode-recursively-using-jackson)

Comment: As @jspcal said, having custom model classes would be the best idea. It is type safe for the JSON being received.